Keras video activity classification model giving uniform prediction probabilities despite good validation accuracy
I am facing an issue with my Keras-based video activity classification model. The model is trained to classify short 5-6 second videos of two persons performing one of three activities: looking at another person's paper, doing their own work, and exchanging papers. I took this model from a paper titled Interaction Relational Network for Mutual Action Recognition whose code is publically available at https://github.com/mauriciolp/inter-rel-net. I am trying to use this model for my specific use case where the input will be keypoints extracted by YOLO11n instead of keypoints extracted by OpenPose.
During prediction, my model consistently outputs the same probabilities for each class for every sample (e.g., [0.15541, 0.62861, 0.21598]), even though it has shown good performance during training with high accuracy. The model was trained on 90 samples (30 samples per class) where each sample was taken from one video, with an average of 80% training and validation accuracy. However, when I use the model for prediction, I receive these almost identical class probabilities for every video.
Model Details:

Training Data: 90 samples, split into three classes (30 samples per class)
Training Setup: 3-fold cross-validation, achieving ~80% average accuracy on both training and validation data.
Input Data: For each video (5-6 seconds), I extracted keypoints (7 joints) of each person from the centeral 60 frames (timesteps) of the video. The Input data for the deep learning model is reshaped into a 3D array: (num_joints, num_samples, timesteps * 2) .
Normalization: The keypoints are not normalized in either training or prediction.
Prediction Problem: The model outputs the same probabilities for each class for each video even if the video is from the training or validation dataset, indicating that it might not be learning well for unseen data.
Keypoints Data: The keypoints for each person in the video are stored in a JSON file, where the file name matches the video name. In the JSON structure, each frame is a key, under which person IDs are keys, and the corresponding 7 keypoints for that person are stored as values. The logic for reading and processing this data has been implemented in the get_groundtruth function.

Code:
Training Code:
   # relation network code


# obtaining data code

DATA_DIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset'
KEYPOINTS_DIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/keypoints'
NUM_FOLDS = 3
ACTIONS = ["Doing own work", "Passing paper", "'looking at each other's paper'"]

def get_train_gt(fold_num, num_folds=NUM_FOLDS):
    """Gets training ground truth for the specified fold."""
    if fold_num < 0 or fold_num >= num_folds:
        raise ValueError(f"fold_num must be within 0 and {num_folds - 1}, value entered: {fold_num}")

    # Get the ground truth with fold assignments
    ground_truth = get_ground_truth()

    # Select all folds except the validation fold
    train_gt = ground_truth[ground_truth['fold'] != fold_num]
    return train_gt

def get_val_gt(fold_num, num_folds=NUM_FOLDS):
    """Gets validation ground truth for the specified fold."""
    if fold_num < 0 or fold_num >= num_folds:
        raise ValueError(f"fold_num must be within 0 and {num_folds - 1}, value entered: {fold_num}")

    # Get the ground truth with fold assignments
    ground_truth = get_ground_truth()

    # Select the specific fold as validation data
    val_gt = ground_truth[ground_truth['fold'] == fold_num]
    return val_gt

def get_train(fold_num, **kwargs):
    """Fetches training data for the specified fold."""
    train_gt = get_train_gt(fold_num)
    X, Y = get_data(train_gt, **kwargs)
    return X, Y

def get_val(fold_num, **kwargs):
    """Fetches validation data for the specified fold."""
    val_gt = get_val_gt(fold_num)
    X, Y = get_data(val_gt, **kwargs)
    return X, Y


# Data generator
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, dataset_fold, subset,
                batch_size=60, reshuffle=False, shuffle_indiv_order=False,
                **data_kwargs):

        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.reshuffle = reshuffle
        self.data_kwargs = data_kwargs
        self.shuffle_indiv_order = shuffle_indiv_order
        self.subset = subset

        if subset == 'train':
            self.ground_truth = get_train_gt(dataset_fold)
        elif subset == 'validation':
            self.ground_truth = get_val_gt(dataset_fold)

        self.num_classes = self.ground_truth.action.max()+1

        num_videos = self.ground_truth.shape[0]
        if subset == 'train':
            self.shuffled_idx = np.random.choice(self.ground_truth.index.values,
                num_videos, replace=False)
        elif subset == 'validation':
            self.shuffled_idx = self.ground_truth.index.values
        self._num_batches = int(np.ceil(num_videos/batch_size))

    def __len__(self):
        return self._num_batches

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_idxs = self.shuffled_idx[
            self.batch_size*idx:self.batch_size*(idx+1)]

        batch_gt = self.ground_truth.loc[batch_idxs]
        batch_x, batch_y = get_data(batch_gt,
            num_classes=self.num_classes, **self.data_kwargs)

        if self.shuffle_indiv_order:
            ### Always swap half of the batch
            num_joints = len(batch_x)//2
            p1_joints = list(range(num_joints))
            p2_joints = list(range(num_joints, num_joints*2))
            swap_index = sorted(np.random.choice(list(range(batch_y.shape[0])),
                batch_y.shape[0]//2, replace=False))
            batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
            batch_x[:,swap_index] = np.squeeze(
                batch_x[p2_joints + p1_joints][:,[swap_index]], axis=1)

        batch_x = tuple(np.array(input) for input in batch_x)
        return batch_x, batch_y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.reshuffle:
            self.shuffled_idx = np.random.choice(self.ground_truth.index.values,
                self.ground_truth.shape[0], replace=False)

# data io
def get_data(gt_split, num_classes, timesteps=16, skip_timesteps=1):
    """
    Processes keypoints data from JSON files for training/testing.

    :param gt_split: DataFrame containing video metadata (action, path).
    :param timesteps: Number of timesteps to consider.
    :param skip_timesteps: Skips frames if provided.
    :return: X (input features) and Y (labels).
    """
    X, Y = [], []
    num_joints = 7
    num_dim = 2

    for video_id, video_gt in gt_split.iterrows():
        action = video_gt['action']
        video_path = video_gt['path']

        with open(video_path, 'r') as f:
            video_data = json.load(f)

        # Prepare storage for keypoints for both persons
        p1_all_joint_coords = [[] for _ in range(num_joints)]
        p2_all_joint_coords = [[] for _ in range(num_joints)]

        # Extract poses for all frames, sorted by frame number
        video_poses = []

        starting_frame = int(sorted(video_data.keys(), key=lambda x: int(x))[0])
        ending_frame = int(sorted(video_data.keys(), key=lambda x: int(x))[-1])

        for frame in range(starting_frame, ending_frame+1, skip_timesteps):
            frame_data = video_data[str(frame)]

            # Extract all persons in the frame
            frame_poses = [frame_data["1"], frame_data["2"]]

            p1 = frame_poses[0]
            for idx, coord in enumerate(p1):
                p1_all_joint_coords[idx] += coord

            p2 = frame_poses[1]
            for idx, coord in enumerate(p2):
                p2_all_joint_coords[idx] += coord

        p1_and_p2 = np.array(p1_all_joint_coords + p2_all_joint_coords)

        # Resize and pad sequences if necessary
        p1_and_p2.resize((num_joints * 2, p1_and_p2.shape[1] // num_dim, num_dim))
        if p1_and_p2.shape[1] < timesteps:  # Padding if not enough timesteps
            pad_val = int(np.ceil((timesteps - p1_and_p2.shape[1]) / 2))
            pad_width = ((0, 0), (pad_val, pad_val), (0, 0))
            p1_and_p2 = np.pad(p1_and_p2, pad_width=pad_width, mode='constant')

        
        center = p1_and_p2.shape[1] // 2
        central_window = slice(center - timesteps // 2, center + timesteps // 2)
        p1_and_p2_center = p1_and_p2[:, central_window].reshape(
            (num_joints * 2, timesteps * num_dim)
        )

        p1_and_p2_center = p1_and_p2_center.tolist()
        X.append(p1_and_p2_center)
        Y.append(action)

    Y = to_categorical(Y, num_classes)
    
    # Reshape X if needed
    X = np.array(X).transpose((1, 0, 2)).tolist()
    size = len(X)
    X = [np.array(X[i]) for i in range(size)]

    return X, Y

def get_kernel_init():

    kernel_init = None
    param = 0.045 # Best for non-normalized coordinates
    kernel_init= initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=param, seed=None)
    
    return kernel_init

def create_relationships(rel_type, g_theta_model, p1_joints, p2_joints):
    g_theta_outs = []

    if rel_type == 'inter':
        # All joints from person1 connected to all joints of person2, and back
        for object_i in p1_joints:
            for object_j in p2_joints:
                g_theta_outs.append(g_theta_model([object_i, object_j]))
        for object_i in p2_joints:
            for object_j in p1_joints:
                g_theta_outs.append(g_theta_model([object_i, object_j]))
        rel_out = Average()(g_theta_outs)
    elif rel_type == 'intra' or rel_type == 'indivs':
        # All joints from person1 connected to all other joints of itself
        for idx, object_i in enumerate(p1_joints):
            for object_j in p1_joints[idx+1:]:
                g_theta_outs.append(g_theta_model([object_i, object_j]))
        indiv1_avg = Average()(g_theta_outs)

        # All joints from person2 connected to all other joints of itself
        for idx, object_i in enumerate(p2_joints):
            for object_j in p2_joints[idx+1:]:
                g_theta_outs.append(g_theta_model([object_i, object_j]))
        indiv2_avg = Average()(g_theta_outs)

        rel_out = Concatenate()([indiv1_avg, indiv2_avg])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid rel_type:", rel_type)

    return rel_out

def create_top(input_top, kernel_init, drop_rate=0, fc_units=[500,100,100],
        fc_drop=False):
    x = Dropout(drop_rate)(input_top)

    x = Dense(fc_units[0], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name="f_phi_fc1")(x)
    if fc_drop: x = Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    x = Dense(fc_units[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name="f_phi_fc2")(x)
    if fc_drop: x = Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    x = Dense(fc_units[2], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name="f_phi_fc3")(x)

    return x

def f_phi(num_objs, object_shape, rel_type, kernel_init, fc_units=[500,100,100],
        drop_rate=0, fc_drop=False, **g_theta_kwargs):
    person1_joints = []
    person2_joints = []
    for i in range(num_objs):
        object_i = Input(shape=object_shape, name="person1_object"+str(i))
        object_j = Input(shape=object_shape, name="person2_object"+str(i))
        person1_joints.append(object_i)
        person2_joints.append(object_j)

    g_theta_model = g_theta(object_shape, kernel_init=kernel_init,
        drop_rate=drop_rate, model_name="g_theta_"+rel_type, **g_theta_kwargs)
    x = create_relationships(rel_type, g_theta_model,
        person1_joints, person2_joints)

    out_f_phi = create_top(x, kernel_init, fc_units=fc_units, drop_rate=drop_rate,
        fc_drop=fc_drop)

    f_phi_ins = person1_joints + person2_joints
    model = Model(inputs=f_phi_ins, outputs=out_f_phi, name="f_phi")

    return model


def g_theta(object_shape, kernel_init, drop_rate=0, fc_drop=False, model_name="g_theta", num_dim=None):
    
    object_i = Input(shape=object_shape, name="object_i")
    object_j = Input(shape=object_shape, name="object_j")

    g_theta_inputs = [object_i, object_j]
   
    x = Concatenate()(g_theta_inputs)

    x = Dense(1000, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name=model_name+"_fc1")(x)
    if fc_drop: x = Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    x = Dense(1000, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name=model_name+"_fc2")(x)
    if fc_drop: x = Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    x = Dense(1000, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name=model_name+"_fc3")(x)
    if fc_drop: x = Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    out_g_theta = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
        name=model_name+"_fc4")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[object_i, object_j], outputs=out_g_theta, name=model_name)

    return model

def get_model(num_objs, object_shape, rel_type, output_size,**f_and_g_kwargs):
    kernel_init = get_kernel_init()

    f_phi_model = f_phi(num_objs, object_shape, rel_type,
        kernel_init=kernel_init, **f_and_g_kwargs)

    out_rn = Dense(output_size, activation='softmax',
        kernel_initializer=kernel_init, name='softmax')(f_phi_model.output)
    model = Model(inputs=f_phi_model.input, outputs=out_rn, name="rel_net")

    return model

def set_callbacks(output_path):
    callbacks_list = []

    checkpoint_filename = ("model-val_loss.keras")
    filepath = os.path.join(output_path, checkpoint_filename)
    modelCheckpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, verbose=0,
                    save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss',
                    save_weights_only=False, save_freq='epoch', mode='min')
    callbacks_list.append(modelCheckpoint)

    log_dir = output_path + '/logs'
    tensorBoard = TensorBoard(log_dir, write_graph=False, update_freq='epoch')
    callbacks_list.append(tensorBoard)

    filepath = os.path.join(output_path, "model-val_acc.keras")
    modelCheckpoint_val_acc = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, verbose=0,
                    save_best_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy',
                    save_weights_only=False, save_freq='epoch', mode="max")
    callbacks_list.append(modelCheckpoint_val_acc)

    earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=100, mode="max",
        verbose=0)
    callbacks_list.append(earlyStopping)

    csvLogger = CSVLogger(output_path + '/training.log', append=True)
    callbacks_list.append(csvLogger)

    return callbacks_list

def train_model(model, verbose, learning_rate, output_path, epochs, train_data, val_data):
  
    if verbose > 0:
        print("Compiling model...")
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                metrics=['accuracy'],
                )

    # Setting up Callbacks
    callbacks_list = set_callbacks(output_path)

    print("Starting training...")

    train_generator = train_data
    val_generator = val_data
    validation_steps = None

    fit_history = model.fit(train_generator,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks_list,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_steps,
        verbose=verbose)
    
    max_acc = np.max(fit_history.history['accuracy'])
    min_loss = np.min(fit_history.history['loss'])
    val_max_acc = np.max(fit_history.history['val_accuracy'])
    val_min_loss = np.min(fit_history.history['val_loss'])

    print("Train - Max ACC: {:.2%} Min loss: {:.4f}".format(max_acc, min_loss))
    print("Valid - Max ACC: {:.2%} Min loss: {:.4f}".format(val_max_acc, val_min_loss))

    return fit_history

def train_rn(output_path, model_kwargs, data_kwargs,
        dataset_fold=None, drop_rate=0.1,
        batch_size=32, epochs=100, checkpoint_period=5, learning_rate=1e-4,
        gpus=1, verbose=2):

    print("Reading data for training IRN ...")

    timesteps = data_kwargs['timesteps']

    if verbose > 0:
        print("> Using DataGenerator")
    train_generator = DataGenerator(dataset_fold, 'train',
            batch_size=batch_size, reshuffle=True, shuffle_indiv_order=True,
            **data_kwargs)
    val_generator = DataGenerator(dataset_fold, 'validation',
            batch_size=batch_size, reshuffle=False, shuffle_indiv_order=False,
            **data_kwargs)
    
    X_train, Y_train = train_generator[0]
    X_val, Y_val = val_generator[0]

    train_data = train_generator
    val_data = val_generator
    
    num_joints = len(X_train)//2
    object_shape = (len(X_train[0][0]),)
    output_size = len(Y_train[0])
    num_dim = object_shape[0]//timesteps

    print("Creating model...")

    model = get_model(num_objs=num_joints, object_shape=object_shape,
        output_size=output_size, num_dim=num_dim, drop_rate=drop_rate,
        **model_kwargs)

    fit_history = train_model(model=model, verbose=verbose, learning_rate=learning_rate,
        output_path=output_path, epochs=epochs, train_data=train_data, val_data=val_data)

    return fit_history

def run_protocol(experiment_name, config, num_reruns=1,
        folds=None, verbose=0, batch_size=20):

    data_kwargs, model_kwargs, train_kwargs = config['data'], config['model'], config['train']
    dataset_folds = NUM_FOLDS

    base_path = f'/content/drive/My Drive/Output/DL_training/{experiment_name}'

    os.makedirs(base_path, exist_ok=True)

    fold_results = []
    for dataset_fold in range(dataset_folds):

        print("Running for fold:", dataset_fold)
        fold_path = f'{base_path}/fold_{dataset_fold}/'
      
        for rerun_idx in range(num_reruns):
            output_path = f'{fold_path}/rerun_{rerun_idx}'

            if os.path.exists(output_path+'/fit_history.csv'):
                hist_df = pd.read_csv(output_path+'/fit_history.csv')
            else:
                fit_history = train_rn(output_path,
                    dataset_fold=dataset_fold, **train_kwargs,
                    data_kwargs=data_kwargs, model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,  gpus=1, verbose=verbose)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    interCONFIG = {
      "data": {
          "timesteps": 60,
          "skip_timesteps": 1,
      },
      "model": {
          "rel_type": "inter",
      },
      "train": {
          "drop_rate": 0.1,
          "epochs": 300,                  
          "learning_rate": 0.0001,
          "checkpoint_period": 1,
      }
    }

    experiment_name = 'IRN_inter'
  
    run_protocol(experiment_name, interCONFIG, verbose=1)


Prediction Code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
SPECIFIC_JOINTS = [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
CLASSES = ["Doing own work", "Passing paper", "Looking at each other"]
NUM_JOINTS = 7
TIME_STEPS = 60
NUM_DIM = 2
MODEL_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Output/DL_training/IRN_inter/fold_0/rerun_0/model-val_loss.keras'
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from ultralytics import YOLO


def classify_dl(video_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    # Get the total number of frames in the video
    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    # Define the range of frames to process (middle 70 frames)
    start_frame = max(total_frames // 2 - TIME_STEPS // 2, 0)
    end_frame = min(start_frame + TIME_STEPS, total_frames)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    # Create a new tracker instance for this video
    model = YOLO("yolo11n-pose.pt")  # Load the model a

    # Loop through the middle no frames
    for frame_num in range(start_frame, end_frame):
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_num)
        success, frame = cap.read()

        if not success:
            break

        # Run YOLOv11 tracking on the frame
        results = model.track(frame, persist=True, max_det=2, classes=[0], verbose=False)

        # Extract keypoints and track IDs from the results
        keypoints = results[0].keypoints.data
        track_ids = results[0].boxes.id.int().cpu().tolist()

        # Initialize dictionary to store the tracked keypoints for this frame
        frame_tracked_keypoints = {}

        # Ensure there are exactly 2 people detected in the frame
        if len(track_ids) != 2:
            raise ValueError(f"Expected 2 persons, but found {len(track_ids)} persons in frame {frame_num}.")

        # Iterate over each person's keypoints
        for person_data, track in zip(keypoints, track_ids):
            person_keypoints = []
            for index in SPECIFIC_JOINTS:
                x, y, conf = person_data[index].tolist()
                person_keypoints.append([x, y]) 
                
            # Store the tracked keypoints for this person
            frame_tracked_keypoints[track] = person_keypoints

        # print(frame_tracked_keypoints)
          # Extract all persons in the frame
        frame_poses = [frame_tracked_keypoints[1], frame_tracked_keypoints[2]]

        p1_all_joint_coords = [[] for _ in range(NUM_JOINTS)]
        p2_all_joint_coords = [[] for _ in range(NUM_JOINTS)]

        p1_coords = frame_poses[0]
        for idx, coord in enumerate(p1_coords):
            p1_all_joint_coords[idx] += coord

        p2_coords = frame_poses[1]
        for idx, coord in enumerate(p2_coords):
            p2_all_joint_coords[idx] += coord

    cap.release()

    p1_and_p2 = np.array(p1_all_joint_coords + p2_all_joint_coords)

    # print("p1_and_p2", p1_and_p2.shape)

    # Resize and pad sequences if necessary
    p1_and_p2.resize((NUM_JOINTS * 2, p1_and_p2.shape[1] // NUM_DIM, NUM_DIM))
    if p1_and_p2.shape[1] < TIME_STEPS:  # Padding if not enough timesteps
        pad_val = int(np.ceil((TIME_STEPS - p1_and_p2.shape[1]) / 2))
        pad_width = ((0, 0), (pad_val, pad_val), (0, 0))
        p1_and_p2 = np.pad(p1_and_p2, pad_width=pad_width, mode='constant')

    center = p1_and_p2.shape[1] // 2
    central_window = slice(center - TIME_STEPS // 2, center + TIME_STEPS // 2)
    p1_and_p2_center = p1_and_p2[:, central_window].reshape(
        (NUM_JOINTS * 2, TIME_STEPS * NUM_DIM)
    )
   
    # print("X", X)
    X = np.expand_dims(p1_and_p2_center, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension
    X = np.array(X).transpose((1, 0, 2)).tolist()
    size = len(X)
    X = [np.array(X[i]) for i in range(size)]

    # Make prediction
    prediction_model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)

    predictions = prediction_model.predict(X, verbose=0)

    # print("Predictions:", predictions)
    final_class = CLASSES[np.argmax(predictions)]

    return final_class

classify_dl('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/68_3.mp4')

I have ensured that the data preprocessing for both training and prediction is identical.
I have used 3-fold cross-validation with good training/validation accuracy and double-checked the data shape and formatting during both training and prediction.
What I Need Help With:

Why is my model giving nearly identical output probabilities during prediction for every sample?
How can I fix this? Is there any problem with the predict fuction?
Is the model being stored properly during validation?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

That's way too much non-runnable code to trawl through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . As a guess, you're reading JSON data when training, but reading video data when inferencing. Have you checked if the coordinates are comparable for both?

Actually, my focus was to show if the code (keras model architecture) was correctly written or not. For prediction, this model will be integrated into a web app, coordinates will be extracted at run time. I have used exactly the same logic for input preparation for both training and prediction. Kindly help me with this problem. Is the model not being stored properly during training or is there a problem with loading it for prediction?
